# ext gwt disable grid selection

Tags: java, grid, selection, gxt

This seems like a simple thing, but after researching, seems like it would require custom implementation. I'm wondering if there's any easy way to disable grid selection for any ext gwt grid (without disabling the grid and having the resultant disabled style set).

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an easier way to disable selections:

```
grid.disableEvents(true);
grid.disableTextSelection(true);
```

Comment: In version 3 of the GXT the call is `grid.disableEvents()`

Answer (score 0):

For disabling table (DataGrid) row in GWT application I use such approach:

```
    SingleSelectionModel<CustomObject> selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<CustomObject>();

...

    private void deselectTableRow() {
        if (selectionModel != null) {
            CustomObject selectedObject = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
            if (selectedObject == null ) {
                return;
            }
            selectionModel.setSelected(selectedObject, false);
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you in case of ext gwt.